# maven failsafe plugin. Copy resources

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

In my project I have created the following directory structure

```
src
  -> main
       -> java
       -> resources
  -> test
       -> java
       -> resources
  -> integration-test
       -> java
       -> resources
```

In my pom.xml I have made following entry

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectory>src/integration-test/java</testSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

If i copy a resource in the src->test->resources it is copied successfully to /target/test-classes automatically. But if I copy a file into /src/integration-test/resources then it is not copied into the target/test-classes at build time.

How can I make the integration test also copy the files inside the resource into the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `integration-test` goal of the maven-failsafe-plugin in by default bound to the `integration-test` lifecycle phase: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html. Therefore, since the `integration-test` phase comes way after the `process-test-sources` [1] (during which test sources are usually copied to the `target` directory) and because I assume what your are referring to by by "build time" is actually the Eclipse "Automatic build" feature, your integration test sources are not copied because Eclipse build stops at the `test-compile` lifecycle phase.

You should check out Maven lifecycle and how to map certains goal to lifecycle phases that fit your needs.

[1] https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Comment: thanks. I solved it by this line `    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/integration-test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>`